# Group by - ignore nulls in the output

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

```
SELECT transacao,
       sum(contravalor),
       sum(valorin),
       sum(valorout),
       divisain,
       divisaout,
       cotacao
FROM caixas_bak
GROUP BY transacao,
         divisain,
         divisaout,
         cotacao
```

---

I am getting this output,

```
transacao      sum         sum           sum       divisain   divisaout cotacao
514171         NULL        NULL     147.300000      NULL          EUR         NULL
514171      150.800000 200.000000        NULL        USD          NULL       0.754000
```

However I need something like this:

```
 transacao  sum              sum          sum      divisain   divisaout cotacao
 514171     150.800000   200.000000  147.300000    USD        EUR        0.754000
```

Basically, i need to ignore the null values in the group by.

How can i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, you can just use `MAX` instead of `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT transacao,
       SUM(contravalor),
       SUM(valorin),
       SUM(valorout),
       MAX(divisain),
       MAX(divisaout),
       MAX(cotacao)
FROM caixas_bak
GROUP BY transacao
```